# Save many records to table without duplicates using java and hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am writing app which take big json file, and save it to db. To do this I use java, spring + hibernate, and my db is MS SQL.

The problem is to save many records(about 25k) to table without duplicates, and it need to be done efficiency.

It's not that I can't resolve this problem at all, it's easy to use method: save instead of saveAll, and with every record, check if this id exist in database. The biggest problem is, to find the way, to do it really efficiency. I save this data many times per day, and also my table have about few millions of records, and it will still grow, so you can imagine how long it can take to check every id.

My column where I need to remove duplicates is 'id' but it is not the key of my table, my key column is 'something_id'.

Another important thing is, I need use transactional, to know which files were saved properly in table.

My ideas so far:

Add unique(id) with (ignore_dup_key = ON) - It does not work, maybe it only works for key column?

Like I said earlier, for now it works with check if 'id' exist in table, if exist I just remove it from map, then save it, but it is slow, and if we will have more records in table it will be only slower.

I have idea to catch exception DataIntegrityViolationException to remove duplicate and run saveAll method once again, and this mechanism would work using recurrency, but sometimes duplicates records are about 25% of whole file, so it may work slow anyway. Also I thought, that I could split file mannualy to use divide and conquer and split it by half when exception occurs then remove record and save only half of the data.

Another idea was to use in transactional annotation - dontRollbackOn and specify DataIntegrityViolationException, but it didn't work.

I would be grateful, if you can just show me some new options, or confirm that one of the ways I tried, is good solution, and I just need spend more time on reading and implementation, because maybe one of my solution didn't worked because I missed something.

Comment: I would create a temporary table, insert all records to it, then call a function inside db which will attempt to insert all data from temp table to your main table, it can go one by one and check if insert failed/succeeded then it will return a list with id to you. It can return only successful or failed or return all id with a column next to it with a number like 1/0 if it was a success or not. Then you delete your temporary table. It should be pretty fast

Comment: but it all depends on how fast your records in table are changing if you need to override record if it already exists etc.

Comment: Another approach (only if records in table are changing slowly) would be to fetch existing id something like ```select id from table where id in (list of id here)``` It will be limited by database implementation for example in Oracle you can put only 2000 items into "in" statement. Then just remove resulted id from your "to insert" list and you will insert only not duplicated ones. In this approach you should have an index on your id which you check for duplication. Also in both approaches you should have constraint "unique" on that id which should be unique

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check these solution. I can even divide it to few batch having 2k items. Also I have unique on my column with id so it  is not a problem.

Comment: After you check which will be better let me know :) I'm curious myself

Comment: Hi, I tried both solutions, and I need to say that the one with temp table is way more efficient. Thanks for help, it works really good.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. I though that temp table would be better. Thanks for feedback :)